# formatting output on the console - Python

Tags: python, formatting

First question here, so apologize for the messy formatting.

I was hoping was a couple of pointers. I'm trying to implement a board game as an exercise for OOP. 
So I need a 8x8 'board', similar to a chess board, but the game play, ie putting pieces on the board only occurs on 7x7 cells. 
I've implemented it by iterating over a list of 8 lists. 
Here's the code:

```
class Board(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.Board = [[[] for x in range(LENGTH)] for y in range(LENGTH)]

    def makeBoard(self, initial_blocked):

        for row in range(LENGTH):
            for col in range(LENGTH):
                self.Board[row][col] = 'e'
        self.Board[0][1] = 'A'
        self.Board[0][2] = 'B'
        self.Board[0][3] = 'C'
        self.Board[0][4] = 'D'
        self.Board[0][5] = 'E'
        self.Board[0][6] = 'F'
        self.Board[0][7] = 'G'

        self.Board[0][0] = '~'
        self.Board[1][0] = '1'
        self.Board[2][0] = '2'
        self.Board[3][0] = '3'
        self.Board[4][0] = '4'
        self.Board[5][0] = '5'
        self.Board[6][0] = '6'
        self.Board[7][0] = '7'

        if True:
            while initial_blocked > 0:
                position_x = rand(0, 7)
                position_y = rand(0, 7)
                if self.Board[position_x][position_y] == 'e':
                    self.Board[position_x][position_y] = 'X'
                    initial_blocked -= 1

        for line in range(8):
            print(self.Board[line])
```

The output looks like this:

```
['~', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
['1', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
['2', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'X', 'X', 'e', 'e']
['3', 'e', 'X', 'e', 'e', 'X', 'e', 'e']
['4', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'X', 'e', 'e', 'e']
['5', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
['6', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
['7', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
```

1st row and column will be used for the user input( e.g. A1, D4) 'X' are cells that are blocked and 'e' stands for empty. The players enter where they want to keep their piece, eg A1, and the 'e' will be changed to 'b' or 'w', black or white. Haven't still figured out how I'll do that, but first things first.
I want it to resemble -at least somewhat- a board. If I try to print out a board using many print()s, I cant figure out how I can change a cell on that board, that references the the same cell as the index. i.e input A1  changes the list at [1][1] and that cell on the board.

I hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Please read [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/48428) and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @Ivonet Thanks for the heads up! Sorry about cluttering up the questions.

Comment: That's ok, but you just need to add a specific question to this. It's not clear what your problem is. Your board looks ok to me, but we could make it a little prettier. Eg, `for row in self.board: print(' '.join(row))`.

Comment: I _think_ you want to know how you can update the printed board after the players make a move. The simple way to do that is to just clear the screen and reprint it. There _are_ ways to modify the stuff that's currently printed, but the details depend on your OS, and it's a bit technical, so it's best to use a library that can handle the messy details. Or forget about doing it in the terminal, and use a GUI to display your board.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a few optimizations to your code that you may find helpful. Rather than doing all of those separate statements to initialise the column and row headers, we can do that using loops. Also, it's good to iterate over lists directly, rather than using indices, when practical. And I've changed some of your names to make them comply with the PEP-0008 style guide; that makes it easier for others to read your code, especially if they're using colour-coded syntax highlighting.

```
from random import seed, randrange

seed(123)

LENGTH = 8

# A dict for converting reference letters to integers
letters = {ch: i for i, ch in enumerate('ABCDEFG', 1)}

def ref_to_index(ref):
    ''' Convert a ref from A1 form to a tuple of (row, col) integers
        Return None if the ref is invalid 
    '''
    if len(ref) != 2:
        return None
    x, y = ref.upper()
    if x not in letters or y not in '1234567':
        return None
    return int(y), letters[x]

class Board(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize the board lists
        self.board = [['e'] * LENGTH for y in range(LENGTH)]
        # Add the column headers
        self.board[0][:] = list('~ABCDEFG')
        # Add the row headers
        for i, row in enumerate(self.board[1:], 1):
            row[0] = str(i)

    def add_blocks(self, initial_blocked):
        for _ in range(initial_blocked):
            while True:
                position_x = randrange(1, LENGTH)
                position_y = randrange(1, LENGTH)
                row = self.board[position_y]
                if row[position_x] == 'e':
                    row[position_x] = 'X'
                    break

    def reset(self):
        ''' Make all the board cells empty '''
        size = LENGTH - 1
        for row in self.board[1:]:
            row[1:] = ['e'] * size

    def show(self):
        for row in self.board:
            print(' '.join(row))
        print()

# test

board = Board()
board.show()
board.add_blocks(7)
board.show()
while True:
    ref = input('Select a move: ')
    idx = ref_to_index(ref)
    if idx is None:
        print('Invalid move')
        continue
    y, x = idx
    row = board.board[y]
    if row[x] != 'e':
        print("That cell isn't empty")
        continue
    row[x] = 'b'
    board.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort! It was your previous comment that hit the nail on the head. {for row in self.board: print(' '.join(row))} I wasn't sure how to avoid printing the list as a whole rather than just the elements. And your other tip about just clearing the screen and printing it out again is genius. Was just going to print out 100 empty lines after each move. Thanks again.